# "Objective C" vs "C++" : difference in statement for method invocation

Tags: c++, objective-c, machine-code

I would like to understand what actually happens when the CPU executes the machine code for the Objective C statement `[ object method ]` with what happens when executing the C++ statement `object->method()`.

There may be significant differences in aspects such as performance or robustness of the application? Why or Why not?

Any reference to examples or evidence is welcome.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but waaaay too broad, especially since method invocation in C++ is different on wether it's a virtual or non virtual method and which compiler compiled it.

Comment: @justsid I dunno: there are 2 common calling conventions in C++.  In Objective C there are also going to be a handful (not sure if more than 1).  The comparison is going to be simple?

Comment: Old but not necessarily outdated article by an Apple runtime engineer on the function ObjC uses for method dispatch: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/

Comment: @Yakk Because that's not all the OP asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casually there can be a significant difference. When you start adding in optimizations and other things, it's less clear.

The primary, basic distinction, is that `[object method]` is a dispatched at runtime, whereas in many cases for C++, it's dispatched at compile time.

So, to dispatch in Obj-C, an actual routine is invoked with a pointer to the object, along with the descriptor of the message, and then the arguments. That routine uses the descriptor to index into the method table for the class, and then invokes the corresponding logic. This is why you can send messages to object that don't actually implement the messages (and thus get dispatch to doesNotImplement). Much of the flexibility in Obj-C is centered upon this runtime dispatch functionality.

In C++, it can be little more than simply invoking an a function through a pointer. With a simple class, the methods are maintained in a static structure at compile time, and the compiler can index directly in to this list to find the function pointer implementing the logic. So at runtime, no search is required. In this regard C++ can ostensibly be faster than Obj-C for method dispatch.

That's the 30,000 foot level. Things are different with C++ virtual methods, and the modern Obj-C runtime. And I can't say anything about the capabilities of modern C++ and how it may have extended it dispatch capabilities. Also, the modern Obj-C runtime is really crazy efficient. I think dispatch on the ARM can be on the order of less than 10 instructions or something like that.

Comment: Note that `foo->method(3);` in C++ does not involve any function (or method) pointers.